# How can I run a ruby script as a service including Sinatra in ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, sinatra

I have written a script that parses my UPS's data via serial interface to a json file, looping indefinitely every 5 secs:

```
require 'json'

pipe = IO.popen("apcaccess")

upsdata_h = {}
data = []

while true 

  pipe = IO.popen("apcaccess")
  upsdata_h[:ups] = {}
  data = []

  while (line = pipe.gets)
    data = line.split(':')
    upsdata_h[:ups][data[0].strip] = data[1].strip
  end

  puts "Internal temperature: #{upsdata_h[:ups]['ITEMP']}"

  File.open("upsdata.json", "w") do |f|
    f.write(upsdata_h.to_json)
  end

  sleep 5 

end
```

I have also another small one to create a tiny api with sinatra:

```
require 'sinatra'

set :bind, '0.0.0.0'

get '/api/upsdata' do
  content_type :json
  File.read('upsdata.json')
end
```

I want to run them both as a service in my ubuntu server 15.04. How do I keep the script running forever in the background as other ubuntu's services ? Should I also include sinatra in the service so it loads on boot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start each service separately with [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/).

An upstart script lives in `/etc/init` with extension `.conf`, like `/etc/init/myscript.conf`.

Here's an example simple upstart script:

```
#!upstart
description "my server"
author      "Me"

start on filesystem
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn

script
    /path/to/ruby /path/to/script
end script
```

Once this piece is in place, you can manually start the service with `start myscript`

Comment: It seems that upstart has been replaced with systemd in the latest ubuntu version.